# How to set conda environment and run scrapy in one batch file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-file, scrapy

I have Anaconda with two environments, and I use second environment "python2" with scrapy. I've tried to run scrapy project "Tutorial" by the following batch file

```
cd "C:\Anaconda\parsing_work\tutorial"
activate python2
scrapy crawl dmoz -s LOG_FILE=out.log -o out.json
```

But my script stops on second line.

How to set conda environment and run scrapy in one batch file?

Comment: You need to source the activate script:
$ . activate python2 or
$ source activate python2

Comment: @neok There's this command on the second line of my batch script, but my script stops on this command.

Comment: If this is a batch file executed by Windows command processor `cmd.exe` and not any other script interpreter, and executed from within a command prompt window to see the error messages, processing of each line results in an error message. On first line the system can't find the specified path on my computer. On second and third line `cmd.exe` can't find a file with name `activate` respectively `scrapy` with a file extension defined in environment variable __PATHEXT__ in current directory or any directory defined in environment variable __PATH__. Is this really a Windows batch script?

Comment: If `activate` is `activate.bat` in current directory and `scrapy` is `scrapy.exe` in current directory, the second line must be `call activate.bat python2`. Sorry if I'm writing not really helpful hints because of no knowledge of about `scrapy` and Python and finding no helpful information (for me) in question itself.

Comment: @Mofi thank you for your answer, it solved my problem!